# Android's /data/system/packages.xml cert data

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-applicationinfo, android-signing

Android's /data/system/packages.xml contains a ***cert*** node that has a "key" attribute. How is that key attribute datastring generated?
For example:

```
<package codepath="/data/app/com.project.t2i-2.apk" flags="0" ft="13a837c2068" it="13a83704ea3" name="com.project.t2i" nativelibrarypath="/data/data/com.project.t2i/lib" userid="10040" ut="13a837c2ecb" version="1">
<sigs count="1">
<cert index="3" key="308201e53082014ea0030201020204506825ae300d06092a86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">
</cert></sigs>
<perms>
<item name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</item></perms>
</package>
```

Comment: To comment on my own question: it appears to be a hexdump of the public key; but I'm not 100% sure..

Answer (score 3):

PackageManager takes it from the signing certificate on the referenced APK.

It can be decoded with `xxd` and `openssl`. Put the data into a file, like `key.hex`:

```
xxd -p -r key.hex | openssl x509 -inform DER -in /dev/stdin -text
```

The data can be produced from the APK with:

```
unzip -p com.project.t2i-2.apk META-INF/CERT.RSA | xxd -p | tr -d '\n'
```

Comment: Thnx. Looking into that -